# How do I get the current Unix timestamp in milliseconds, in D?

Tags: d

How can I get the current unix timestamp (milliseconds since January 1st, 1970) as a `long` variable?

In other words, how would I implement this function?

```
long getUnixTimestampMillis() {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer!

There are two functions in std.datetime.systime: `stdTimeToUnixTime` and `unixTimeToStdTime`, which convert between unix time (*seconds* since 1970-1-1) and stdTime (hecto-nanoseconds since Proleptic Gregorian Calendar epoch) See the docs for [unixTimeToStdTime](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_datetime_systime.html#.unixTimeToStdTime)

If your intent is to pass the value into a function that accepts a typical unix time (in seconds, not milliseconds), then you can the following function:

```
time_t getUnixTimestamp() {
   import std.datetime;
   return Clock.currTime().stdTime().stdTimeToUnixTime();
}
```

However, if your goal truly is milliseconds since the unix epoch, the OP's code is correct. But here is a condensed version that doesn't rely on the unix epoch knowledge (this is how `stdTimeToUnixTime` works internally). The key is that `SysTime(unixTimeToStdTime(0))` gives a `SysTime` that is set at the unix epoch. From there you can do whatever math you like.

```
long getUnixTimestampMillis() {
    import std.datetime;
    return (Clock.currTime() - SysTime(unixTimeToStdTime(0)))
        .total!"msecs";
}
```

Comment: this answer gives the total seconds, not the milliseconds like the question asked for.

Comment: Oof you are right. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did some experimentation on my own, and I came up with the following solution:

```
long getUnixTimestampMillis() {
  import std.datetime;
  SysTime now = Clock.currTime();
  SysTime unixEpoch = SysTime(DateTime(1970, 1, 1), UTC());
  Duration diff = now - unixEpoch;
  return diff.total!"msecs";
}
```

However, I'm open to suggestions for how to improve this!